# PD controller, sweep all values of Kd and Kp that satisfy system stability

Tags: matlab, pid-controller

Is there a way in Matlab to take a transfer function, define `H` (closed loop system) and sweep all values of `Kp` and `Kd` that allow the system to be stable?

```
clear all
clc
close all
s = tf('s');
Gs = tf(0.001667,([1 12.04 20.52 0.8342]));
H = -1;
subplot(3,1,1)
step(feedback(Gs,H))
hold on
grid on
title('Step serponse without a PD controler')
Kp = 1;  %-147700.5<Kp<2500
Kd = 0;
subplot(3,1,2)
C = pid(Kp,0,Kd);
T = feedback(C*Gs,H);
t = 0:0.01:140;
step(T,t)
grid on
title('Step response with a PD controler')
subplot(3,1,3)
rlocus(T)
title('Root locus to check for stability')
grid on
stability = isstable(T)
```

I'm aware that I can use a Routh Hurwitz stability test to find range of `Kp` and `Kd` values that satisfy stability but is it possible to do this in Matlab without Routh Hurwitz table? I'm not trying to tune this system for a specific function - yet.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of. Your best bet is to use [`pidTuner`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/pidtuner.html) to tune the PID gains:

```
pidtuner(Gs,'pd') % open PID tuner for plant Gs with PD controller
```

or

```
pidtuner(Gs,'pdf') % open PID tuner for plant Gs with PD controller & approximate derivative
```